# OpenLDAP: ACLs using sockname and DN?

Tags: openldap, access-control-list

In OpenLDAP (2.4.45, on FreeBSD), I'm trying to constrain the access of a DN to an attribute, by giving a DN access only when the connection is made via a socket; but without success.

What I'm trying is

```
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword
  by dn.base="uid=pwreset,ou=service,dc=example,dc=edu" 
     sockname.exact="/var/run/openldap/ldapi"
  write
```

(the idea is that the `pwreset` DN can be used by an automatic password-reset script, but that that DN will have that access only when the script is running on the same machine as the LDAP server).

This `by` phrase appears to match the production in Sect. 8.3 of [the OpenLDAP access control documentation](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html), and the remark in slapd.access(5) that the items in the `<who>` field ‘may be specified in combination’.  And indeed there are no syntax warnings generated.  I'm presuming that the combination implies an *AND* rather than an *OR* – this isn't made explicit in the documentation.  I can find no examples covering this in either OpenLDAP documentation or on the web.

This stanza works when the `sockname` element is absent, suggesting that the configuration is otherwise working as I expect.

When I try to write the `userPassword` attribute using this DN, I get an `ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)` error.

The OpenLDAP documentation doesn't (somewhat surprisingly) explicitly state what the effect of this `sockname` element is, and the slapd.access(5) page says, rather obliquely, that:

> The statements `peername=<peername>`, `sockname=<sockname>`, `domain=<domain>`, and `sockurl=<sockurl>` mean that the contacting host IP (in the form `IP=<ip>:<port>` for IPv4, or `IP=[<ipv6>]:<port>` for IPv6) or the contacting host named pipe file name (in the form `PATH=<path>` if connecting through a named pipe) for peername, the named pipe file name for sockname, the contacting host name for domain, and the contacting URL for sockurl are compared against `pattern` to determine access.

That doesn't actually say very much.

Have I completely misunderstood the point of this access specification, or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax (for this version of OpenLDAP, at least) is:

```
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword
  by dn.base="uid=pwreset,ou=service,dc=example,dc=edu"
     sockname.exact="PATH=/var/run/openldap/ldapi"
     write
```

Thanks to Quanah Gibson-Mount on [the openldap-technical list](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201803/msg00036.html) for pointing to the solution.